# Application a style to all page xaml wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a style file "dark.xaml" that I will use to style all xaml pages, so I place it in "application.xaml". But why my xaml page can't to access the style of "dark.xml"?

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="/rtwin;component/style/Dark.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `ResourceDictionary` source it seems that you are adding style from an assembly (correct if I'm wrong).

Well, in that case, you need to add `pack://application:,,,` so that your final App.xaml should look like this,

```xml
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/rtwin;component/style/Dark.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Could've upvoted the answer so others can get benefitted from similar question.